# Almacenar varios valores en una sola variable utilizando un for en C#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Esto es exactamente lo que necesito hacer y lo que se me pide y no se me premite usar ningún array (si es que no es posible sin un array me lo dicen, para informar que no es posible)
Problema: Mostrar operaciones
matemáticas

Escriba un programa que permita ingresar 10 números por teclado y nos
muestre posteriormente la suma, resta, multiplicación y promedio de los
números ingresados.
Tenga en cuenta que el usuario escribirá los números en la consola.

Especificaciones
• Implementa tu programa en un proyecto de consola llamado
ciclos.cs.

• Tu programa pedirá al usuario diez números y los almacenará en
una variable llamada valor.

• Crea una variable llamada suma, donde se almacenará la suma de
los valores que ingreses.
• Crea una variable llamada promedio, donde se almacenará el
promedio de los números ingresados.
• Utiliza un ciclo for para pedir al usuario que ingrese diez veces un
valor.
• Imprima las variables suma y promedio.

Y no tengo idea de como hacer, ya que si intento hacer un for no se me ocurre que puedo hacer, adjunto el código que he hecho

```
using System;
```

namespace Ciclos
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int valor;
int suma;
byte times = 1;

```
        for (times = 1; times == 5; times++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("digite su valor numero "+ times);
            valor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine("digite su valor numero " + times);
            suma = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            valor = valor + suma;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Podrías almacenar cada valor dentro de un array y fuera del for realizar los cálculos que te solicitan. Además la condición de tu for esta mal, debería ser times <= 10, no == 5

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera se me olvidó de poner eso, lo que me pidieron es que no puede tener arrays y gracias por lo de la condicion del for, no me habia dado cuenta que puse 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá la solución

```
            int suma = 0;
            int promedio;

            Console.WriteLine("::::INGRESE 10 NUMEROS AL AZAR::::");

            for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese el #{x}");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                suma += input;
            }

            promedio = suma / 10;

            Console.WriteLine($"La suma es {suma} | el promedio es {promedio}");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Lo que debes hacer primero es leer el número que ingresa el usuario con `Console.ReadLine()`, este debemos convertirlo a `int` para poder realizar operaciones con el, ya que *por defecto se toma el input del usuario como `string`*. Luego este valor se lo vamos sumando por cada vez que entra al ciclo a la variable **suma**.

Para el promedio simplemente dividimos la suma con el total de números ingresados y listo!

Nos comentas si te sirve, y si no entiendes alguna línea sólo me lo haces saber ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, solo no entiendo esos Console.WriteLine(""); que están en blanco, osea no entiendo su utilidad

Comment: Simplemente es para darle saltos de linea al texto, asi no queda tan junto todo

Comment: Se agradece mucho tu ayuda y una ultima cosa, como funciona la x , si nunca se declara esa variable?

Comment: Si te fijas la variable *suma* comienza en 0. La idea es que por cada vuelta al `for`, osea las 10 veces que el usuario debe ingresar los números, va a guardar ese número ingresado en la variable *input*, y luego con los símbolos `+=` le vas sumando cada valor a suma y así se va acumulando el total; seria lo mismo que hacer esto suma = numero1 + numero2+ numero3... se entiende?

Comment: En cuanto a la x que mencionas, es una variable que vive sólo dentro del for, y si se declara como primera condición del ciclo (`int x = 1`); esta se limita a funcionar como contador de cada vuelta al ciclo, por eso especificamos que debe comenzar en 1, ir  aumentando de 1 en 1 y no entrar más al ciclo si su valor es mayor a 10

Comment: Ahora si ya entendí, muchas gracias por la explicación